# AVAudioRecorder currentTime giving bad values

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

I have a setup as follows, testing on an iPhone 5s with iOS 10.3, both in and out of debug.

- An `AVAudioRecorder` fires `record(forDuration: 5.0)`
- A `CADisplayLink` watches the levels of the recorder (the recorder is `meteringEnabled`), synchronizing an animation, and keeping track of `recorder.currentTime` (but the problem can be reproduced by minimally keeping track of time in the display link)
- The reports of `recorder.currentTime` consistently reach values > 5 (often 5.2 to 5.5).  The results are essentially consistent with the values of `recorder.deviceTime` and `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`
- I initialize an `AVAudioPlayer` and verify that the sound asset does have a duration of precisely 5.0 seconds.

From my understanding, the recorder's `currentTime` is measured in seconds, and resets to 0.0 when recorder.isRecording reverts to false, which happens immediately when the recorder stops (this is consistent with what i see in `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording`)... so observing with a `CADisplayLink` should produce currentTime values strictly less than 5.0?

The question is: what could be going wrong here? The recorder is stopping as it should after exactly 5 seconds, but internally it thinks it recorded for more than 5 seconds? I'm listening to all my recordings and they sound fine.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but my `AVAudioSession` is of type `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`, and my audio settings are as follows (all of these excepting sample rate are necessary for later analysis):

```
audioSettings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
    AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: 0,
    AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: 0,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
    AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: 0
]
```

I already tried fiddling with all of these and didn't see any change behavior.

The `CADisplayLink` is added from the main thread via

```
recorderDisplayLink?.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
```

The only similar question I can find on stack exchange is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620841/avaudiorecorder-losing-last-seconds), but the question is underspecified and the answer unhelpful (for me at least).
At first I thought maybe the issue is with overloading the main queue, so that somehow the recorder's sense of time becomes bloated (which I think 
 would still constitute bad behavior), but after disabling the animation (and also experimenting with a Timer instead of a CADisplayLink), the problem persists!!!  Perhaps it is still a threading problem, but I don't see why that would be the case.  And if i do need to multi-thread, I could use some help both with understanding and implementing :)
Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: So is the question why are you getting between 0.2 and 0.5 extra seconds than the duration requested with `recordForDuration:`?

Comment: The question is, how are the following two statements simultaneously compatible:
(1) record(forDuration: 5.0) produces a valid recording of exactly 5.0 seconds
(2) A timer observing the currentTime property of the recorder in action reports values significantly > 5.0

Comment: TL;DR `AVAudioRecorder` isn't very good, replace it. see my answer for a  more nuanced version of this.

Comment: You cannot have an iphone 4 with iOS 10.3, the last supported version on this device is iOS 7.1.2. Even if you've meant 4s that would still set the max version to iOS 9.3.5

Comment: Haha thank you! You're right.  Corrected question.

Answer (score 4):

Of all the times I've used `AVAudioRecorder`, I've eventually had to replace it. `AVAudioRecorder` is a general purpose recording class, so once your requirements get a little specialised, it will disappoint you.

However, it does do metering, which is what attracts many people to it. So maybe the situation can be salvaged.

Possibilities:

a. if `currentTime` isn't trustworthy, then don't observe it! You've got your 5 second files, so maybe find some other way to mark that passage of time in your app.

b. of the the property `currentTime`, the header file says:

> ```
>   only valid while recording
> ```

Are you sampling `currentTime` only while recording? If so that could be the problem. In which case you could use the `deviceCurrentTime` property, which is always valid, although you will have to subtract off the initial `deviceCurrentTime`.

If the situation can't be salvaged, you could pretty quickly replace `AVAudioRecorder` with `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioFile`, but that's a question for another day.

Comment: Yea I was thinking about replacing it, but would like not to if possible... and it is the metering that attracted me. Basically I am watching the recorder's average power both to feed an animation and gauge silence.  It's the second part for which I need the `currentTime` property.  But I need these times to be consistent with `AVAudioPlayer` and `AVReader`'s perception of time.

Comment: Oh and also I should clarify:  I'm only reporting the values of `currentTime` when `isRecording` is true.  That means either that the recorder is still recording when `currentTime` exceeds the actual audio duration, or that `isRecording` does not actually indicate what the recorder is doing.  But perhaps the header says it all.  "`Only valid while recording (but don't bet on it)`"

Comment: I did try to use the `deviceCurrentTime` property of the recorder, but found it to behave just as strangely.  Maybe I should use a different measure of device time, outside of the recorder?

Comment: Yes, some other way of marking time that isn't `AVAudioRecorder`.

Comment: Actually I tried marking time with `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` and I'm seeing the same problem.  The amount of system time that the `isRecording` flag reads true is really longer than the `duration`

Comment: With `AVAudioEngine` you can monitor time elapsed by counting samples recorded, I don't think you'll get more accurate than that. Level metering isn't that hard, just sum up the squares and fudge with a scaled log, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem for a UILabel that I was updating on a Timer but was able to workaround it by checking if the gap between the timer triggers was too big and remembering the delta as a currentRecordTimeOffset.

```
     if ( self.recorder.recording ) {
         float adjustedRecordTime = self.recorder.currentTime;
         if(self.currentRecordTimeOffset == 0){
             if(self.recorder.currentTime - self.lastRecordedTime > 1.0){    // current time should be updated every 0.1 so a 1 Sec delta indicates offset needed
                 self.currentRecordTimeOffset = self.recorder.currentTime;
                 adjustedRecordTime = self.recorder.currentTime - self.currentRecordTimeOffset;
             }
         }
         else{
             adjustedRecordTime = self.recorder.currentTime - self.currentRecordTimeOffset;     // get rid of the unusual offset
         }
         self.lastRecordedTime = self.recorder.currentTime;
         self.durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", adjustedRecordTime];
```